# Trying to split each line by comma Groovy

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to do some tests in groovy for integration in my pipeline. Basically what I want is to split each line of the csv folder by commas.
Imagine I have in file1.csv this content:
Rice,true,Good
Pasta,false,Bad
Chicken,true,Ok
With my groovy method, I want to split the csv by commas and have a list of strings of the food.
But when I'm trying to print to see if the split is happening I get an error message.

Caught: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'D:\Desktop\test\file1.csv' with class 'java.lang.String' to class 'groovy.lang.GString'

Can someone help me out understand what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks :)

```
def test() {
    def mapParts = [:]
    readFile("D:\\Desktop\\test\\file1.csv" as GString).splitEachLine( /,/ )
            { it ->
        println it
    }
}
```

Comment: why don't you `new File("D:\\Desktop\\test\\file1.csv").splitEachLine( /,/ ){ println it }`

Comment: with new file works well thank you :) but why I need to use "new File" instead of readFile to not get that error? Just for I understand clearly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work in plain Groovy:

```
new File("D:\\Desktop\\test\\file1.csv").splitEachLine( /,/ ){ 
  println it 
}
```

The option with `readFile` as per [ref-doc](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-basic-steps/#readfile-read-file-from-workspace) and [this example](https://code-maven.com/jenkins-readfile-writefile) requires a map:

```
readFile(file: "D:\\Desktop\\test\\file1.csv").splitEachLine( /,/ ){ 
  println it 
}
```